# tornado's warning [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, tornado

starting tornado,and wait for a while,this warning coming out.i have no idea what is this error about.how to fix the warning?

```
WARNING:root:Read error on 12: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
WARNING:root:error on read
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/tornado-2.4-py3.2.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 355, in _handle_read
    if self._read_to_buffer() == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/tornado-2.4-py3.2.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 422, in _read_to_buffer
    chunk = self._read_from_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/tornado-2.4-py3.2.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 403, in _read_from_socket
    chunk = self.socket.recv(self.read_chunk_size)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Maybe when your server handling a connection,but the client dropped it .What's the ratio of this error?

Comment: You should check whatever you are connected to to check what happened. As for what error `104` (also known as `ECONNRESET`) means, see e.g. [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2979806/440558).

Comment: I am also facing same issue  while opening pdf document using url  link. Please suggest, how can i ensure the connection  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe two  aspects:

one:
Use the old tornado version, the bugfix is: https://github.com/facebook/tornado/commit/3258726fea5bcd1b401907653bc953ce63d5aeb2

two:
Something wrong with your client who sends this request, RST without ACK(It is ok as RFC defined)